# Drupal views slideshow returning only one result

Tags: drupal, plugins, view, drupal-views, slideshow

[Views slideshow](http://drupal.org/project/views_slideshow) for [Dupal](http://drupal.org/) is amazing … there are no other words for it. I have used it on a few projects with little to no issues at all. However, the current project that I am working on isn't going as smoothly.

When the 'View style' is set to unformatted the preview returns the right amount of nodes but when slideshow is selected the query returns only one result. Puzzlingly, the SQL is exactly the same.

[image: Screenshot of the basic settings for slideshow]

Can you shed some light on the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Does the source show only one too? 
Maybe the source (HTML) contains all the entries, but the Javascript fails to slide to the next item.

Comment: Thanks for the advise. Unfortunately, the source shows only one entry also. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution is the following:
Click the gear icon next to the Slideshow style to edit its settings.
Select your slideshow mode from the drop-down menu. Select SingleFrame.
Enter a value for the *Timer delay* input box. Enter 4000, as an example.
Enter a value for the *Initial slide delay offset* input box. Enter 2000, as an example.
Complete the rest of the settings to your liking.
Click update to submit that form, then click Save to save your view.
Hope it helps.